# When Clients is more than normal , IIS is down and my site is unavailable

Tags: c#, sql-server, web-services, web, iis-7.5

I have a website and a web-service that work together. The website connects to the web service to call any method and do anything that is related to the database.
The web-service connects to the database and gets data and the response to the website.

When users connect to the site (more than 200), IIS goes down and my site becomes unavailable.

I remote connected to the server and restarted the SQL Server and IIS services, but it didn't work. If I change the application pool of the website from .NET 2 to .NET 4 and change again to .NET 2, the website and web service are both okay.

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to IIS, then on the left pane select Sites folder, you'll get list of all websites in the center pane. Find your website there, right click and select "Set Website Defaults" from the context menu. Check your limits there. See pic below:

[image]